# flow_images_from_directory to save augmented images

Tags: r, keras, data-augmentation

I'm trying to user Keras package in R just to augment my images and use it for training. I could not find example or walk through of how to use it. I'm a R-user with very limited python knowledge.
I did:

```
datagen <- image_data_generator(
rescale = 1/255,
rotation_range = 40,
width_shift_range = 0.2,
height_shift_range = 0.2,
shear_range = 0.2,
zoom_range = 0.2,
horizontal_flip = TRUE,
fill_mode = "nearest"
)
train_dir <-"/home/images/"
train_generator <- flow_images_from_directory(
 train_dir,
 datagen,save_to_dir = "/home/Augmented_images/",
 target_size = c(150, 150),
 batch_size = 32,
 class_mode = "binary"
 )
```

I understand that this is just a iterator, but how should I run it to be able to save my file? There are python examples, but couldn't find any with R.

Comment: First, you have to define your model and then fit the model, in order to save the augumented images in the indicated folder by  `save_to_dir`.  For example define your model using `model <- keras_model_sequential(...) ` and then fit it using `model %>% fit_generator(...)`.

Comment: What if I din't want to have a model? I just wanted to augment the images.

Comment: You can define a dummy model and fit it just to obtain your augumented images. I do not know of other way of saving the augumented images to your `save_to_dir`